# Bundle columns of a DataFrame into hierarchical index

Tags: python, pandas

If I have preexisting columns (say 12 columns, all with unique names), and I want to organize them into two "header" columns, such as 8 assigned to `Detail` and 4 assigned to `Summary`, what is the most effective approach besides sorting them, manually creating a new index, and then swapping out the indices?

Happy to provide more example detail, but that's the gist of what is pretty generic problem.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use multi-index of columns capability.  It's important to `rename()` columns before `reindex()` so no data is lost.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({f"col-{i}":[random.randint(1,10) for i in range(10)] for i in range(12)})
header = [f"col-{i}" for i in range(8)]
header
# build a multi-index
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(["Header" if c in header else "Detail", c]) 
                           for c in df.columns], names=('Category', 'Name'))
# rename before reindex to prevent data loss
df = df.rename(columns={c:mi[i] for i,c in enumerate(df.columns)}).reindex(columns=mi)

print(df.to_string())
```

**output**

```
Category Header                                           Detail                    
Name      col-0 col-1 col-2 col-3 col-4 col-5 col-6 col-7  col-8 col-9 col-10 col-11
0             5     5     6     1     8     3     8     6      8     2      8     10
1             2     7    10     5     2    10     5    10     10     7      6      1
2            10     1     1     2     7     9     2     9      4     4      7      6
3             8    10     1     3     3     4    10    10      9     7      6      8
4             6     8     7     2     5     4     3     3      7     9      8      6
5             6     4     4     4     1     5     8     4      4     1      6      8
6             3     7     3     8     8     4     6     1      5    10      5     10
7             5     1    10     9     9     7     8     2      6     7     10      4
8             2     2     1     4     8     8     7     2      5     9      9      9
9             8     6     5     6     2     8     2     8     10     7      9      3
```

Comment: What step here orders the columns if the first 8 columns aren't in "Header", rather every other column is in "Header"?

Comment: then just re-order your columns before you build the multi-index `header = ["col-5","col-7","col-11"]
# make sure header columns are moved to start...
df = df.reindex(columns=header+[c for c in df.columns if c not in header])`

Comment: Ah, okay. I was hoping to avoid having to manually sort the columns, thinking Pandas might have a specific way to link up columns to a new level.